# Finite groups $G$ such that $Soc(G)$ is abelian and contains normal subgroups only

Tags: group-theory

This question is a generalization of a previous one: [Groups such that any nontrivial normal subgroup intersects the center nontrivially](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36564/groups-such-that-any-nontrivial-normal-subgroup-intersects-the-center-nontriviall) (see Jack Schmidt's answer):

What finite groups $G$ have the property that $Soc(G)$ is abelian and all of the subgroups of $Soc(G)$ are normal in $G$? (the linked question talks about the case where $Soc(G)$ is central and thus is a special case).

Comment: @user3533: "all of its subgroups"; you mean all subgroups of $G$, or all subgroups of the socle of $g$? I'm guessing the latter, but "its" is ambiguous here. You may want to clarify by saying "all subgroups of..." instead of "all of its subgroups".

Comment: @Arturo: I mean subgroups of $Soc(G)$. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following are equivalent for an abelian subgroup N of the finite group G:

- every subgroup of N is normal in G
- every cyclic subgroup of N is normal in G
- for every g in G, there is a positive integer k, such that for every x in N, x<sup>g</sup> = x<sup>k</sup>.

In this case we say that G **acts as power automorphisms** on N.

When N = Soc(G), then we can add another condition:

- every minimal normal subgroup is cyclic of prime order, and those of the same order are isomorphic as modules

Suppose that not only G, but also H = G/Soc(G), and K = H/Soc(H), etc. all act as power automorphisms on their socle.  In this case, not only is every minimal normal subgroup cyclic, but in fact every [chief factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_series) is cyclic, and so the group is what is called [supersolvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group).  A finite nilpotent group is one in which every chief factor is the 1-dimensional trivial module.  A finite supersolvable group is one in which every chief factor is (any) 1-dimensional module.

Power automorphisms are discussed a bit in Roland Schmidt's textbook on the Subgroup Lattices of Groups.

When all of the p-chief factors for each prime p are required to be isomorphic inside a particular normal subgroup (not the socle), then I believe this characterizes "PST" groups.  In case we require it in the socle, I'm not immediately sure, but there might be something important there.

Comment: @Jack: Just to make sure I understood: if $G$ is a finite solvable group, then $Soc(G)$ is abelian, but there may be a subgroup of $Soc(G)$ which is not normal in $G$. But if $G$ is a finite supersolvable group then $Soc(G)$ is abelian and each subgroup of $Soc(G)$ is normal in $G$. Right?

Comment: @Jack: That's what I understood is implied by your answer. I'm making sure because it seems to me that in the solvable case the subgroups of $Soc(G)$ will be normal in $G$ too. Maybe I'm just confused, still thinking about it.

Comment: @Jack: My reasoning is that if $G$ is finite and solvable then its minimal normal subgroups are cyclic of prime order, and this is one of the "equivalent conditions" you mentioned.

Comment: @user3533: your first is exactly correct.  Look at the alternating group of degree 4 (and order 12, a solvable but not supersolvable group).  Its socle has order 4 and is itself a minimal normal subgroup.  A sylow 3-subgroup sits on top of the socle and swirls the subgroups of order 2 around.  In a solvable group every minimal **subnormal** subgroup is cyclic of prime order, and every **composition** factor is cyclic of prime order.  However, minimal normal subgroups and chief factors are only of prime power order.

Comment: @Jack: I understand now. Thank you.I'm still trying to figure out why condition 4 implies the others. When condition 4 applies, the socle is a product of vector spaces and conjugation by an element of G acts on each vector space as a diagonal operator. But we need it to be a special diagonal operator, namely - multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: @user3533: You are quite correct!  The 4th condition is not equivalent. 3×Sym(3) has every minimal normal subgroup cyclic of order 3, but one is central and one is inverted, and so there cannot possibly be a "k" as in the third condition.  Furthermore any "diagonal" subgroup like { (x,x) : x in Z/3Z } is contained in the socle but normal.  So condition 4 is weaker.  I'll fix it, but then I have to ask myself if we now have a stronger condition since condition 4 really is the "supersolvable" condition, not 1=2=3.

Comment: @Jack: So the new condition 4 may be stronger than the others, but it still holds for any supersolvable group?

Comment: @Jack: I understand why in a supersolvable group, $G$, any minimal normal subgroup is cyclic of prime order, but I'm not sure why the action of $G$ on $Soc(G)$ by conjugation is an action by (universal) power automorphims.

Comment: @user3533: The new condition 4 is equivalent to the first three conditions (when N=Soc(G) is abelian).  The group G=S3×S3 is supersolvable, but does not satisfy condition 4.  The action on Soc(G) is not by a universal power automorphism, and the two minimal normal subgroups are not isomorphic as G/Soc(G)-modules.

Comment: @Jack: That's clear now. Thank you very much for all the help.