# Finite non-abelian groups such that $Soc(G)=G$

Tags: group-theory, socle

Let $G$ be a finite group. It is possible that $Soc(G)=G$.
For example: if $G=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$ for some primes $p_1,\dotsc,p_n$ (not necessarily distinct), then $Soc(G)=G$.

Can this happen for non-abelian groups?
If the answer is affirmative, can we find a condition that guarantees that $Soc(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$?

**EDIT**: It always happens if $G$ is simple, so there are non-abelian examples. The question about a general condition remains though.

**EDIT**: A related question is: for which groups does it hold that taking $Soc$ some finite number of times results in an abelian group. That is: $Soc(Soc(Soc(\dotsm G\dotsm)))$ is abelian for some finite number of iterations of taking the socle.

Comment: What is the definition of $Soc(G)$?

Comment: @Asaf: $Soc(G)$ is the subgroup generated by all minimal nontrivial normal subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(All groups are finite.)

The following are equivalent:

- $G$ is a direct product of simple groups
- $G ={\rm Soc}(G)$, that is, $G$ is the product of its minimal normal subgroups

Such a group is called **completely reducible**.

From this it should be clear that ${\rm Soc}({\rm Soc}(G)) = {\rm Soc}(G)$, that is, ${\rm Soc}$ is idempotent.  Hence the following are equivalent:

- ${\rm Soc}({\rm Soc}(...({\rm Soc}(G))...))$ is abelian
- ${\rm Soc}(G)$ is abelian
- Every minimal normal subgroup is (elementary) abelian

I don't know a name for such groups, but in line with the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37922/finite-groups-g-such-that-socg-is-abelian-and-contains-normal-subgroups-onl), an abelian socle only requires that the minimal normal subgroups are modules at all.

If one requires an abelian socle not only of $G$, but also of $H=G/{\rm Soc}(G)$, and $K=H/{\rm Soc}(H)$, *etc.*, then one gets [solvable groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group).  So:

- nilpotent means every chief factor is a one dimensional module and central
- supersolvable means every chief factor is a one dimensional module
- solvable means every chief factor is a module

When people define iterated socles, they usually mean:

$$\newcommand{\Soc}{\operatorname{Soc}}
\Soc^{n+1}(G)/\Soc^n(G) = \Soc( G/\Soc^n(G) )$$

This is sometimes called the (upper) **Loewy series** of $G$.

Comment: The first equivalence should be a little surprising since minimal normal subgroups need not be simple (just direct products of simples).  However, for a minimal normal subgroup **not** to be simple, there has to be something above it to swirl its factors around.  If G=Soc(G), then there is nothing on top to do the mixing.

Comment: @Jack: "If one requires \emph{this}". Are you referring to the condition "$Soc(G)=G$" or to "$Soc(G)$ is abelian"?

Comment: One more caveat: it is not true that the socle is the largest normal subgroup that is a direct product of simple groups.  For instance, in any non-abelian p-group of exponent p, the center is the socle, but the center is always contained as a maximal subgroup in some abelian subgroup, which is a direct product of simple groups of order p since the exponent is p.  For instance, the Sylow p-subgroup of GL(3,p) is like this.

Comment: @user3533: this = "Soc(G) is abelian".  Thanks for catching it.  My phrasing was unclear.  If G=Soc(G), then G/Soc(G)=1 is pretty dull.

Comment: @Jack: Thank you! When you say "is a module" do you mean it's an abelian group?

Comment: @user3533: Yup, that is a fine way to think of it.  I do mean a little more than that: It is an abelian group N such that G/N acts on it as automorphisms, and so I might distinguish between the abelian group of order 3 that is central and the abelian group of order 3 that is not.  Both are modules, but they are different modules.